# Properly escaping quotes when running a command in kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I want to run a mongodb command in Kubernetes deployment.
In my yaml file, I want to run the following:

```
command: ["mongo --port ${MONGODBCACHE_PORT} --host ${MONGODBCACHE_BIND_IP}  \
                  --eval "rs.initiate('{ _id: \"test\", members: [ { _id: 0, host: \"${MONGODBCACHE_BIND_IP}:${MONGODBCACHE_BIND_IP}\" },]}')"  && \
                  ./mycommand "]
```

I checked that the environment variables are present correctly. How do I escape the characters when running this command?

Comment: So, (1) you didn't specify what **error** you are experiencing (2) `command:` is actually an array of strings with each one being an individual shell "word", so it is overwhelmingly likely that the syntax you provided will look for an executable named "mongo --port ...etcetc"

Answer (score 2):

Use only `mongo` in command and the others in args field which is an array. Like,

```
command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
args:
- mongo
- --port
- ${MONGODBCACHE_PORT}
- --host
- ${MONGODBCACHE_BIND_IP}
- --eval
- rs.initiate('{ _id: "test", members: [ { _id: 0, host: "${MONGODBCACHE_BIND_IP}:${MONGODBCACHE_BIND_IP}" } ] }')  && ./mycommand
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

got it working with a slightly modified configuration in manifest :

```
command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
args:
- /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p$DB_ROOT_PASS -h $DB_HOST -e "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS $DB_USER@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$DB_PASS';"
```

Although it's mysql cli client this should work for any other command.

ENV Variables must exists of course.